# How to let an object appear in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an animation that may stop at 2 points depending on what the user fills in, if the animation stops at one of the two frames an objects has to apear and have to disappear if the user continues with playing the animation again. Can someone tell me how I can let object appear if the animation stops at a certain frame?
Do I need something like this? I have very little experience so please help!

```
star_mc._alpha = 0; star_mc.onEnterFrame = function(){ if(this._alpha < 100){ this._alpha = this._alpha + 5; }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok.... try it... just put it in the right place!
It's hard to tell where because I don't know how your animation built!!

Comment: the code is in AS2 , but the only tag is AS3 .. so is the code ok?

Comment: @Yitschak if you know a code in as3 with the same effect you`re welkome i'm codeing in as3 but the only thing is that the code above get activated directly i guess but it has to be activated if the other animation stops at an frame so the code has to change but how??

Comment: It's hard to guess how your .fla built... I need to see it to help... there are a lot of ways how to do it properly and I think that the animation will help to decide